# Apps Script - Copying and deleting rows older than 6 months

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to implement a Google Apps Script that runs once a month. The script will check the rows of the source sheet, and any rows older than 6 months - according to a column within the sheet called 'date', will be moved to a new target sheet. Once moved, the rows would be deleted from the source sheet.

I was able to implement the copy logic here:

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetid_source'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Source'); // ss = source sheet
  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetid_target'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Target'); // ts = target sheet
  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

}
```

But i have no idea on how to:

- Select the rows older than 6 months
- Additively add the new rows to the target sheet (I do not want to delete anything previously loaded)

The format of the data I am trying to move is the following:

### col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | date

With the date column deciding if something is older than 6 months.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
const shSource = ss.getSheetByName('Source')
const shTarget = ss.getSheetByName('Target')

function myFunction() {
  const COL_DATE = 4
  const HEADER_HEIGHT = 1
  if(shSource.getLastRow()==HEADER_HEIGHT){
    return
  }
  const data = shSource.getRange(1+HEADER_HEIGHT,1,shSource.getLastRow()-HEADER_HEIGHT, shSource.getLastColumn())
  data.sort(COL_DATE) // prepare for deletion of continous rows
  const minDate = new Date()
  minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth()-6)

  
  const rowsToDelete = data.getValues().filter(row=>row[COL_DATE-1]<minDate)
  if(rowsToDelete.length>0){
    console.log(`Delete ${rowsToDelete.length} rows where date is before ${minDate}`)
    shTarget.insertRowsAfter(shTarget.getLastRow(), rowsToDelete.length)
    shTarget.getRange(shTarget.getLastRow()+1,1, rowsToDelete.length, rowsToDelete[0].length).setValues(rowsToDelete)
  } else{
    console.log(`No rows to delete`)
  }

  shSource.deleteRows(HEADER_HEIGHT+1, rowsToDelete.length)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Copy and Delete Rows Older than Six Months**

```
 function copyanddeleterowsolderthansixmonks() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth()-6,dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const ssr = 2;
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.ssid); 
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet0'); 
  const srg = ssh.getRange(ssr,1,ssh.getLastRow() - ssr + 1,4);
  const svs = srg.getValues();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.testsourceid); 
  const tsr = 2;
  const tsh = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  let d = 0;
  let oA = [];
  svs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let rdt = new Date(r[3])
    let rdtv = new Date(rdt.getFullYear(),rdt.getMonth(),rdt.getDate()).valueOf()
    if(rdtv < dtv) {
      oA.push(r);
      ssh.deleteRow(i + ssr - d++);
    }
  });
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Source Sheet:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 9 | 13 | 1/26/2020 |
| 19 | 13 | 17 | 2/26/2020 |
| 15 | 3 | 6 | 3/26/2020 |
| 1 | 9 | 4 | 4/26/2020 |
| 1 | 7 | 10 | 5/26/2020 |
| 6 | 8 | 14 | 6/26/2020 |
| 12 | 7 | 0 | 7/26/2020 |
| 6 | 17 | 19 | 8/26/2020 |
| 3 | 19 | 4 | 9/26/2020 |
| 14 | 17 | 10 | 10/26/2020 |
| 7 | 19 | 2 | 11/26/2020 |
| 3 | 18 | 12 | 12/26/2020 |
| 2 | 9 | 17 | 1/26/2021 |
| 10 | 2 | 0 | 2/26/2021 |
| 0 | 7 | 4 | 3/26/2021 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4/26/2021 |
| 10 | 14 | 10 | 5/26/2021 |
| 18 | 15 | 11 | 6/26/2021 |
| 1 | 7 | 18 | 7/26/2021 |
| 15 | 11 | 15 | 8/26/2021 |

Source Sheet after function:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 | 0 | 2/26/2021 |
| 0 | 7 | 4 | 3/26/2021 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4/26/2021 |
| 10 | 14 | 10 | 5/26/2021 |
| 18 | 15 | 11 | 6/26/2021 |
| 1 | 7 | 18 | 7/26/2021 |
| 15 | 11 | 15 | 8/26/2021 |

Destination Sheet:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 9 | 13 | 1/26/2020 |
| 19 | 13 | 17 | 2/26/2020 |
| 15 | 3 | 6 | 3/26/2020 |
| 1 | 9 | 4 | 4/26/2020 |
| 1 | 7 | 10 | 5/26/2020 |
| 6 | 8 | 14 | 6/26/2020 |
| 12 | 7 | 0 | 7/26/2020 |
| 6 | 17 | 19 | 8/26/2020 |
| 3 | 19 | 4 | 9/26/2020 |
| 14 | 17 | 10 | 10/26/2020 |
| 7 | 19 | 2 | 11/26/2020 |
| 3 | 18 | 12 | 12/26/2020 |
| 2 | 9 | 17 | 1/26/2021 |